# IMEI Number Missing - Possible NVRAM.img Flashing - CMDLet to Rewrite the IMEI Number? - Or Other Solutions?

Tags: imei

I was trying to Root my Revvl 6 5G and I believe that I might have flashed a blank nvram.img in my bootloop recovery. Now my IMEI number is missing, and I get a signature failure anytime I try to sideload a root.zip. Is there an `adb shell <command>` or `python mtk w <command>` that can repair a missing IMEI number? Or another possible solution?

Comment: Unless you have installed a custom recovery, sideloading is restricted to original firmware images. If you try to load a non-genuine ROM you will get a signature failure.

Comment: That makes sense. So the missing IMEI has nothing to do with it. Unfortunately, there is no recovery.img to patch for custom recovery. I achieved root last night with a magisk_patched-boot_a.img.